# Center link in an unordered list element (flexbox)

Tags: html, css, html-lists, flexbox

I've been playing around with flex box and I would like to center the "Logo" test in the upper left corner vertically in its blue container.

You can see it here: http://codepen.io/TimRos/pen/MwKNgw

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.box {
    color: white;
    font-size: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 3px black;
}


/* COLORS & Style
===================================== */

.main-header    {   background: #e3e3e3;    }
.main-footer    {   background: #e3e3e3;    }
.main-content   {   background: #e3e3e3;    }

.main-wrapper {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #333;
}


.main-wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* HEAD
===================================== */

.main-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.main-nav {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 100%;

}

.main-nav li {
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

#logo {
    margin-right: auto; /* Align Logo to Left, Nav to the right*/
    margin-left: 0;
    align-self: center;
}

.main-nav li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.main-nav li {
    background-color: #3f8abf;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid firebrick;


}
.main-nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
}

#logo {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 4px solid firebrick;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;

}

#logo h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


/* CONTENT
===================================== */

.main-content {
    padding: 15px;
}
h3 {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/* FOOTER
===================================== */

.main-footer {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

I tried margin and padding auto but that doesnt seem to work, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a bit more research and found another solution to this problem. Since I'm already using flexbox anyways, might as well use flexbox like this:

```
#logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}
```

As I said, the other solution works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this CSS:

**CSS**

```
#logo a{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); // For Safari and Chrome Mobile
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgyg2a4r/8/)**

Comment: thank you! while this works flawlessly it seems kind of unintuitive/hacky, why is there no standard property which can do this? it seems like an everyday thing to do?